# Unable to capture Twilio Sms error response in PHP

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I have written the following php code to send sms in one file:

```
<?php
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

function sendSMS($twilioAPIKeys, $messageBody) {

 try {
   $to = "+919915183552";

   // $twilioAPIKeys is an array which contains twilio credentials
   $sid = $twilioAPIKeys['AccountSID'];      
   $token = $twilioAPIKeys['AccountToken'];
   $from = $twilioAPIKeys['twilio_number'];
   $client = new Client($sid, $token);

   $message = $client->messages->create("$to", // to
                    [
                        "body" => "$body",
                        "from" => "$from"
                    ]         
            );

    print_r($message->sid);
 }
 catch(Exception $ex) {
    print ($ex->getMessage());
 }
}

?>
```

In second php file, I am including first file and calling that function as follows:

```
try {
         sendSMS($twilioAPIKeys, 'Hi, it is first sms');
         writeLog ("Now, I am writing a status in log");
         saveInDatabase();
    }
    catch(Exception $ex) {
       print_r("outer exception", $ex->getMessage());
    }
```

I am facing an issue when any error occurs while sending sms. When sms send successfully, then code works fine. But problem is: there is no output printed for statement `print_r($message)`  for exception or error in sms sending and if error occurs, then 400 error exists in second file of php, but further progress of php code is also halted and error does not enter in catch block.

How to get `print_r($message)` or response code or delivery status of outbound twilio sms in catch part of first file, but sms error is entering in catch block of second file, how to enter in catch part of first file only for sms error?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($message);` to confirm the response is of the type you are expecting? If the 400 error "exists in apache log files" then clearly the error is on your server and not Twilio's.

Comment: Also `$to = +919915183552;` is not what you want to do. It's a phone number, not an integer.

Comment: @miken32- I have updated. Now, how to capture error if number is unverified for trial twilio?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not catch the exception because it was already caught by the earlier code. An exception can only be caught once after being thrown. If you want to catch it again, you need to throw it again.

```php
<?php

function sendSMS($a, $b)
{
    try {
        // do stuff
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "First exception! " . $e->getMessage();
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Then in your second file:

```php
try {
    sendSMS($a, $b);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Second exception! " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I also want this. My problem is catch is caught at second file in your example. I want catch should be run at first file according to your example.